# Send multiple data in a single request using Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to send multiple data from different MongoDB tables to the same landing page in a single GET request using below code where:

- `as` and `bs` are MongoDB database tables names
- `landing` is the *ejs* filename (`landing.ejs`)

Code:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  as.find({}, function(err, founda) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("landing", {
        a: founda
      });
    }
  });

  bs.find({}, function(err, foundb) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("landing", {
        b: foundb
      });
    }
  });
});
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){

    as.find({},function(err,founda){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            bs.find({}, function(err2, foundb) {
                if (err2) {
                    console.log(err2);
                } else {
                    res.render("landing",{a:founda, b: foundb});
                }
            });


        }
    });
});
```

Basically you need to make the call to `b` after making the call to `a`. If you're looking to do them simultaneously, you would need to look into `promises`.

The code above would need better error handling as well ...

Comment: "If you're looking to do them simultaneously, you would need to look into promises "
not necessarily, he can make use of async parallel with a callback style

Comment: If as is empty then an error will occur and it will not go to the else block.
So bs and render statement are dependent whether as works.
If as is empty it should not affect the execution of bs.

Answer (score 0):

if your output depends on 2 async operations, you need to nest them in callbacks or promise or async await

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    as.find({},function(err,founda){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
          bs.find({},function(err,foundb){
            if(err){
               console.log(err);
            }else{
               res.render("landing",{a:founda,b:foundb});
            }
          });
        }
     });
  });
```

// async parallel example

```
async.parallel({
    one: function(callback) {
        as.find({}, function(err, founda) {
           if (err) {
              callback(err, null);
           } else {
              callback(null, founda);
           }
        });
    },
    two: function(callback) {
        bs.find({}, function(err, founda) {
           if (err) {
              callback(err, null);
           } else {
              callback(null, foundb);
           }
        });
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    res.render("landing",{a:results.a,b:results.b});
});
```

Comment: I want them to be executed irrespective of one another.

Comment: i have added a parallel example, which will run them irrespective of each other, but your final render is still going to be after both complete

Comment: An absurd question  again. Why you want send two different res.render.

Comment: @Rejat dont waste your time please.

Comment: @ŞükranEken, everyone starts somewhere. i am glad that op tried something, even though it's fundamentally wrong.  i think the fundamental issue with your original post was that you cant send 2 responses back.